# Save or return REST service response from within a function in NodeJs

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest

I am trying to return an service response from within a function, however the function returns the values before the service execution is ended and hence I always get a null value in return.

I tried using callbacks but not working though I haven't tried promises. Can I use them inside another function?

my code snippet:

```
    function getBoonInfoByISisbn(isbn, jsonString) {

    var result = null;

    var requestURL = domainURL + "getbkinfbyisisbn?isbn=" + isbn;
    mongoClient.registerMethod("getbkinfbyisisbn", requestURL, "GET");

    var args = {
        // data: {
        //     isbn:isbn
        // },
        headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" }

    };

    var apiRequest = mongoClient.methods.getbkinfbyisisbn(args, function (data, response) {
        // console.log(data); - getting data output on console
        result = data; /*this has data*/
    });

    return result; /*this is always null*/
}
```

This service returns a single JSON object, if exact match or null if not an exact match

I want to use this details elsewhere in my code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Promise:

```
function getBoonInfoByISisbn(isbn, jsonString) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        let requestURL = `${domainURL}getbkinfbyisisbn?isbn=${isbn}`;
        mongoClient.registerMethod("getbkinfbyisisbn", requestURL, "GET");
        let args = {
            headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/json"
            }
        };
        mongoClient.methods.getbkinfbyisisbn(args, (data, response) => {
            resolve(data);
        });
    })
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried using the promise before with 'promisify-node' npm package, that totally was returning empty {} (WT*) , did not knew sometimes things can be less painful without libs. Thanks again mate

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to return an async result. Try to use a Promise to return the value when it arrives. See here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function

Hope this helps ;)

Answer (score 0):

Callbacks are asynchronous...so `return result` will execute before anything within `apiRequest` and that's why `result == null`. Try using async/await as an alternative. More on that [here](https://javascript.info/async-await)

Comment: I tried using async await with my function, however the mongo client doesn't return a promise, so can not use the async-await, so no use. What I want to do is somehow promisify client method(get/post) and return a promise so that I can use the result out side my function.